# Can docker stage be reused multiple times?

Tags: docker

Let's say we have a docker multi-stage build like:

```
FROM node as base
# create file 1

FROM base as build
# create file 2
# edit file 1

FROM base as prod
COPY --from=build something
# do we have file 2 here?
# was file 1 changed?
```

Does any change at `build` or any other stage affect `base`?

For example at base stage we can do something like installing `pnpm` or setting env without repeating it in `prod` and `build` stages.

Usage example:

```
FROM node as base
RUN npm add -g pnpm
ENV TZ="UTC"

FROM base as build
COPY ./ ./
RUN pnpm install
RUN pnpm build

FROM build as dev
# no need to do any optimizations
CMD ["node", "./server.js"]

FROM build as build_no_node_modules
# Delete node_modules recursively in cwd
RUN find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -exec rm -rf '{}' +

# I want to be sure that `build` stage didn't change `base`
# and no `node_modules` were installed
FROM base as prod
COPY --from=build_no_node_modules ./ ./
# install only production deps
RUN pnpm install --prod --no-optional
CMD ["node", "./server.js"]
```

Comment: Can you explicitly state the question?

Comment: @Marat hope it's better now

Comment: Do you mean you wish to change one of the lower layers without changing the ones on top of it? Do you mean you wish to use an earlier `build` for multiple `dev` environments? Your question is unclear.

Comment: I'm pretty sure each build stage starts its own COW layer, so they should not affect each other, and it should be safe to reuse them.

Comment: Try changing your prototype file to use `touch`, `echo`, `ls`, and `cat` to manipulate files; what do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Docker image can't be changed once it's built.  This rule applies to image stages in exactly the way you describe: once you start another stage `FROM` some image, the `base` stage can't be modified at all.  This even applies to individual `RUN` lines, meaning that the line that tries to delete the old `node_modules` directory does hide the files but the resulting image (stage) is actually larger.  (In your actual file, since you `COPY` the stage files into another stage, it's probably okay.)

This does in fact mean you can have separate build stages that have different `node_modules` directories, even if they start from a base with some common setup.  You could use this to install the full set of dependencies, build your application, and then have a second stage with only runtime dependencies:

```bash
FROM node:lts AS base
# reuse across all stages: common directory
# with at least the package dependency files installed
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

FROM base AS build
# install full dependencies and build it
RUN npm ci
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm build

FROM base
# install only runtime dependencies, copy in built application
ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN npm ci
COPY --from=build dist/ dist/
CMD ["node", "dist/index.js"]
```